# how to setup a secure commercially licensed API access to a web service?

Tags: web-services, security, rest, soa

I need to serve a SOA application though an AJAX/REST API. The service need to be sold to customers which will be able to host a JS on their sites which will let their users communicate with our webservice.

Needs:

- the customer only should put a one line  in its page, no server side code
- the script should authenticate and download the API js code to communicate with the enabled services (depending on the licensing options the customer buy)
- the overall path should work without having the customer's users to see logins nor certificates

I can't find a pattern to fullfill the previous requirements at the same time. Do you have suggestions? 
I've considered various options, but at the minimum thet reuire to install server side code on my customer's machines, but I cannot do it (they have their own third party hostings, of various nature).

Thanks a lot,
Giovanni